# What version of PyQt should I install (32 vs 64)

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, 32bit-64bit

I'm running Windows 8.1 **64bit** but have Python 2.7.10 **32bit**. Now I'm trying to install PyQt using Windows installer. What version should I download?

> PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe    Windows 64 bit installer
>
> PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32.exe    Windows 32 bit installer

I have **64bit** windows but **32bit** Python and I want to make a 32bit executables.

I think that I should install **32bit**, is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would guess you're right since python will link to PyQt they should be based on the same architecture !